# angular.js http servlet filter called twice

Tags: angularjs, servlet-filters

I have below code to call spring rest service. The problem i am facing is, if i add the headers as shown in the below code then i am seeing servlet filter is called twice and in the first time authorization value is null and in the second call authorization value is present. If I make the call without header then servlet filter is called only once. I dont understand why this behaviour. can anyone please help me to understand why this behaviour or let me know how i can pass the header and ensure its called only one time.

```
$scope.getMessage = function(eventStatus){

        if (angular.isUndefinedOrNull(eventStatus)){
            eventStatus = "";
        }

        $http({method: 'GET', url: "http://localhost:8080/AppWeb/service/events?page="+$scope.currentPage + "&eventStatus="+eventStatus+"&sort=createdDate,desc&startDate=&endDate=" ,headers:  {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer edc4e9af-b2e2-4037-8dd4-15432df78cec'
        } }).
                success(function(data) {
                $scope.messages = data.content;
                }).
        error(function(status) {
        window.alert("Unexpected Error.");
        });

        }
```

Comment: If page is being opened from different port than your REST is on then first request is an OPTIONS preflight request as per CORS spec. Those preflight requests have no payload and the only thing that gets returned in them is proper CORS headers

Comment: If you use custom headers there will be a preflight request (well, there are [ways](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain)). Don't fight it. Just let it happen. Configure your server to accept it. http://enable-cors.org/server.html More reading:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @charlietfl: is there anything i can do to handle this issue in angular js side. I am just launching the html page from the directory no server used for client side code.

Comment: @ippi; I already have cors filter implemented in the server side. but it looks oauth filter executes before cors filter. i feel if cors filter executes before oauth probably will resolve this issue. trying at both client side or server side to resolve this issue

Comment: NO.. javascript has no control over preflight...the browser does that internally as part of CORS specification. You need to adapt your server code